# More efficient way to get frequency counts across columns of data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some survey data in which columns correspond to items and rows correspond to customers saying how likely they are to buy each item. Looks like this:

```
item1 = c("Likely", "Unlikely", "Very Likely","Likely") 
item2 = c("Likely", "Unlikely", "Very Likely","Unlikely")
item3 = c("Very Likely", "Unlikely", "Very Likely","Likely") 
df = data.frame(item1, item2, item3)
```

I want a summary table giving the percentage of  each response for each item. Right now I'm using table() on each column for this process, and its a lot of code to manipulate. How can I do this using plyr or apply or something faster?

Current solution:

```
d1<-as.data.frame(table(df$item1))
d1$item1_percent<- d1$Freq/sum(d1$Freq)
names(d1)<-c("Response","item1_freqs","item1_percent")

d2<-as.data.frame(table(df$item2))
d2$item2_percent<- d2$Freq/sum(d2$Freq)
names(d2)<-c("Response","item2_freqs","item2_percent")

d3<-as.data.frame(table(df$item3))
d3$item3_percent<- d3$Freq/sum(d3$Freq)
names(d3)<-c("Response","item3_freqs","item3_percent")

results<-cbind(d1,d2[,2:3],d3[,2:3])
```

Note I don't really need the freq counts, just the percentages.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `lapply(df, function(x) prop.table(table(x)))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have the same range of values in each item# you can use

```
sapply(df, function(x) prop.table(table(x)))
#             item1 item2 item3
# Likely       0.50  0.25  0.25
# Unlikely     0.25  0.50  0.25
# Very Likely  0.25  0.25  0.50
```

But if they were different you can set each item# to have a common set of levels

```
df[] <- lapply(df, factor, levels=unique(unlist(df)))
sapply(df, function(x) prop.table(table(x)))
```

Comment: It would be easiest if you try to deal with these at an earlier stage. When reading in, say, using `read.table` set `na.strings=c("", " ")`. Or you could set these blank values to missing `df[df == ""] <- NA` ...

Comment: i deleted that question which made you look like youre talking to yourself lol sorry. but basically i did sapply(df, function(x) prop.table(table(x,exclude=""))) to control for the blanks in my data

Comment: Good stuff. I do think it is better to try and sort these things out though at an earlier stage as dealing with them will become more difficult as your analysis becomes more complex.

Comment: Very true. Is there a na.rm type function that would take all of the blanks out of my df across all columns? Each column has the same number of blanks, because each person was asked about the same number of items, but the items rotated.... I don't need to keep the user IDs or anything for the rows.

Comment: Def easier to convert these values to NA, as this will open up more standard tools to remove. It is also good to do this as it creates explicit steps in your analysis, which *hopefully* you will understand  6 months later when you look at your r script. But if you want to remove any rows in your data with any blank ("") spaces you could do `df[!as.logical(rowSums(df=="")), ]`

Comment: Yeah issue there is that just because someone has a blank for item1, that doesn't mean they have blanks for all items. so i don't want to remove entire rows.

Comment: ah right okay. well if you are stuck with them id convert them to real NA's (full circle)

Answer (score 3):

Using `dplyr`:

```
results = data.frame(df %>% 
                     group_by(item1) %>% 
                             summarise(no_rows=length(item1)/nrow(df)))
results = cbind(results,
          data.frame(df %>%  
                     group_by(item2) %>%
                             summarise(no_rows=length(item2)/nrow(df))))

results = cbind(results,
          data.frame(df %>% 
                     group_by(item3) %>% 
                             summarise(no_rows=length(item3)/nrow(df))))


# > results
#        item1 no_rows       item2 no_rows       item3 no_rows
# 1      Likely    0.50      Likely    0.25      Likely    0.25
# 2    Unlikely    0.25    Unlikely    0.50    Unlikely    0.25
# 3 Very Likely    0.25 Very Likely    0.25 Very Likely    0.50
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful. I have many more than 3 columns, though. Might do something like "for (col in colnames(df)){results=cbind(results, data.frame(df %>% group_by(col) ..... <all your code> "    Unless theres a better way ?

Comment: Matt! Don't yo think apply can be helpful. cc:@SarahCummings

Answer (score 3):

Consider the chain merge with `Reduce` where you first loop through each column of dataframe by number with `lapply` to build a list of dataframes that is then passed into `merge` on *Response*:

```
dfList <- lapply(seq_along(df), function(i){      
  d <- as.data.frame(table(df[,i]))
  d$item1_percent <- d$Freq/sum(d$Freq)
  # PASS COLUMN NUMBER INTO DF COLUMN NAMES
  names(d) <- c("Response", paste0("item",i,"_freqs"), paste0("item",i,"_percent"))

  return(d)      
})

results2 <- Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x, y, by="Response", all.equal=TRUE), dfList)

# EQUIVALENT TO ORIGINAL results
all.equal(results, results2)
# [1] TRUE
identical(results, results2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a different way of organizing the data, using factor levels to differ the items. This makes it easy to work with the data. I will transform your data using the gather function, and then use summarise to calculate the frequency percentages:

```
library(tidyverse)

results <- df %>% 
 gather("item", "likelihood") %>% 
 group_by(item, likelihood) %>% 
 summarise(n = n() ) %>% 
 mutate(freq = n / sum(n))

# > results
#  A tibble: 9 x 4
#  Groups:   item [3]
#    item  likelihood     n  freq
#   <chr>       <chr> <int> <dbl>
# 1 item1      Likely     2  0.50
# 2 item1    Unlikely     1  0.25
# 3 item1 Very Likely     1  0.25
# 4 item2      Likely     1  0.25
# 5 item2    Unlikely     2  0.50
# 6 item2 Very Likely     1  0.25
# 7 item3      Likely     1  0.25
# 8 item3    Unlikely     1  0.25
# 9 item3 Very Likely     2  0.50
```

I used dplyr and broom for this, but I prefer using the tidyverse library, since it loads both packages at once.

Edit: If you want to use keep the frequencies as columns, you can use spread to do so:

```
col_results <- results %>% 
  select(-n) %>% 
  spread(item, freq)

# > col_results
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#   likelihood item1 item2 item3
# *       <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1      Likely  0.50  0.25  0.25
# 2    Unlikely  0.25  0.50  0.25
# 3 Very Likely  0.25  0.25  0.50
```